# Is this commercial use when using OSS library only in develop environment?

Tags: commercial, software

I don't know the definition of "commercial use" very much.

Is this commercial use when using OSS library only in develop environment?
I don't use the OSS library in production environment.

Comment: Why do you need to know the definition of "commercial use"?

Comment: As background, I want to use the OSS library whose license is Super Source. But I have no idea whether I could use it for only develop environment.

Comment: Super Source is not a license. It's the name of the library. If I believe this page https://www.npmjs.com/package/super-source it is distributed under the MIT license. Have you considered reading the license https://spdx.org/licenses/MIT? It's very short and straightforward.

Comment: Sorry for bothering you, but I meant super source https://supso.org/.

But thank you for your information https://spdx.org/licenses/

Comment: Oh well OK but if the library is only distributed under the Super Source license (whose text is there https://supso.org/licenses/super-source/license), then this is not OSS (because this license does not follow the OSD as described in @amon's answer). PS: I think you should edit your question to give way more information.

Answer (score 5):

The [Open Source Definition](https://opensource.org/osd) describes the fundamental values of open source software. One of these values is that Open Source software may be used for *any purpose*, including commercial usage. So it is not important for an open-source license whether you are using a library in development or in production. This is in contrast to some proprietary licenses which often do make such a distinction.

However, the details depend entirely on the exact license of the library, so please do read the license terms. If the project doesn't have a license, you have no right to use. But you may freely use code under one of the  MIT, Apache, or GPL licenses for any purpose, including a production or development environment. The terms of these licenses only start kicking in if you copy the software outside of your organization.

A handful of Open Source licenses also have terms that apply during the use of the software, without making copies:

- The BSD 3-clause license has a minor restriction regarding advertisements.
- The Apache 2 and GPLv3 licenses prevent you from suing for patent infringement under certain circumstances.
- The AGPL triggers not only when passing on copies of the software, but also when providing access to the running software over a network. This makes webapps more like ordinary applications from a user perspective.